# How to enable sync manager in electron?

Tags: javascript, electron, service-worker

I am building an offline cross-platform using electron. It uses a service worker to make the app offline first. When I try to register the sync manager through following command:-

```
swRegistration.sync.register('myFirstSync')
```

**Expected behavior**

On the page with a service worker registered, this snippet should produce no errors.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(swRegistration) {
  return swRegistration.sync.register('myFirstSync');
});
```

**Actual behavior**

When running with an electron, I get

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Background Sync is disabled.
```

I need to enable sync manager. Any idea of how it can be done?

Comment: what is your electron version?

Comment: I have electron 8.2.2

Comment: This error is coming from the renderer?

Comment: And is this for adding push notification?

Comment: There is an existing issue with electron - https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9802

Comment: Akash. yes but issue is open.

Answer (score -1):

According to [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com)

You just have to follow this article, which is on their website and you can see it on the site by clicking [here.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync)

This is the article:

**How to request a background sync**

In true extensible web style, this is a low level feature that gives you the freedom to do what you need. You ask for an event to be fired when the user has connectivity, which is immediate if the user already has connectivity. Then, you listen for that event and do whatever you need to do.

Like push messaging, it uses a service worker as the event target, which enables it to work when the page isn’t open. To begin, register for a sync from a page:

```
//register your service worker:
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')

//then, later, request a one-off sync:
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(swRegistration) {
  return swRegistration.sync.register('myFirstSync');
});
```

Then listen for the event in /sw.js:

```
self.addEventListener('sync', function(event) {
  if (event.tag == 'myFirstSync') {
    event.waitUntil(doSomeStuff());
  }
});
```

And that's it! In the above, doSomeStuff() should return a promise indicating the success/failure of whatever it’s trying to do. If it fulfills, the sync is complete. If it fails, another sync will be scheduled to retry. Retry syncs also wait for connectivity, and employ an exponential back-off.

The tag name of the sync ('myFirstSync' in the above example) should be unique for a given sync. If you register for a sync using the same tag as a pending sync, it coalesces with the existing sync. That means you can register for an "clear-outbox" sync every time the user sends a message, but if they send 5 messages while offline, you'll only get one sync when they become online. If you want 5 separate sync events, just use unique tags!

Comment: You misunderstood the question. I know how to start background sync. My question was how should we start the background sync in electron. Electron has to give me a message Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Background Sync is disabled.